# Make the string value which contains aspx page name to type of Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have stored my page name and path in database. Now I want to retrieve the name and path and then want to access the particular page controls of the selected page. Is there any way I can achieve this in asp.net C#

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: not really, i am getting stuck in whatever i am trying

Comment: `Response.Redirect("~/MyPage.aspx");`
and then
`_____.FindControl("mycontrol");`.

Comment: I don't have anything like redirect . In page load I get the file name and path of some other page from database. There itself i need to convert it to type of Page and use it to find the control of that page.Thanks